# HTML - Overlay not covering the whole window

Tags: html, overlay

Overlay not covering the whole window but just a portion of the window as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT5c2.png)

Here is the code is used:

```
#table { 
                  z-index:2000; 
                  position:absolute; 

                  bottom:0; 
                  left:0; 

                  width:100%;
                  height: 100%; 
                  background:#000; 
                  opacity:0.45; 
                  -moz-opacity:0.45; 
                  filter:alpha(opacity=45); 
                  visibility:hidden; 
                } 


  <div id="table"  style=" height: 300px;display:none;"></div>
```

And when the onSelect() function is called, the following code is executed:

```
        function onSelect(){
                document.getElementById('table').style.display = "block";
                var o = document.getElementById('table'); 
                o.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
```

And If I click on that overlay div I should hide the overlay again. Any idea how?

Comment: For your second question: Can you include all your `html` and `css` and `javascript`?  Thanks

Comment: Can I please get some feedback, did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question,

set your `z-index` value lower on your `#table` until it is covered.